# PHPUnit codecoverage of my Symfony bundle does not work

Tags: symfony, phpunit

In those days made a tool in a selfmade framework, and setted up unit tests with PHPUnit for that (whitout Symfony). Then i could make tests with codecoverage whitout problems.

Now i migrated my tool as a Symfony bundle. I can test it now with no errors (whitout codecoverage)

I googled and didn't found anything about *CodeCoverage.php undefined notice* problems.

```
phpunit -c app src/myVendor/myBundle/

..............................................................  62 / 139 ( 44%)
.............................................................. 124 / 139 ( 89%)
...............
Time: 14.5 seconds, Memory: 45.00Mb
OK (139 tests, 5733 assertions)
```

But when i add the logging configuration for codecoverage, the execution will crash. **But it worked before i migrated my tool into a bundle**.

```xml
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
         stopOnError="true"
         stopOnFailure="true"
         stopOnRisky="true"
         stopOnIncomplete="true"
         stopOnSkipped="true"
>
    <logging>
        <log    type="coverage-html"
                target="C:/Users/FPI/Desktop/PHPUnit_CodeCoverage/html"
                lowUpperBound="35"
                highLowerBound="70"/>
        </logging>
</phpunit>
```

I recieve this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Notice: Undefined offset: 4658' in phar://C:/bin/phpunit/php-code-coverage/CodeCoverage.php on line 694

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined offset: 4658 in phar://C:/bin/phpunit/php-code-coverage/CodeCoverage.php on line 694

Call Stack:
   34.3818   45467848   1. Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException() D:\Projekte\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php:0
```

Thanks in advice for help. PHPUnit v 4.6.9. PHP 5.5.26.

Comment: Can you update PHPUnit to the latest version? Did you whitelisted the coverage to the strict minimum of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jean, an PHPUnit update fixed this issue.